# How to Eliminate CSS Jitter In Navigation

Tags: html, css

I have a header with a navigation and a logo. When I click the links in the nav I have some jitter in the links.
The links are moving on click to add a background image which is positioned to the left of the `img`
This is causing the links to move around in order to adjust according to their padding.

I am having trouble trying to fix this. I tried to replicate the problem on JsFiddle but was unable to. When I remove the padding the links are too close together and when I add a width I seem to have the same problem...

This is my css for the navigation,

```
header {
    padding: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

header img {
    padding-left: 2em;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}
nav {
    float: right;
    padding: 1em 6em 0em 0em;
}

nav a {
    color: #000000;
}

nav a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1em; 
}

nav a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ed7b5c;
}

nav a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url("../icons/o.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center; 
}

nav a.active {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url("../icons/o.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
    padding-left: 30px; 
}
```

This is the `html`

```
<header>
    <img src="images/headerLogo.png" alt="Wuno, Inc.">
    <nav><ul>
<li><a href="#">home</a></li>
<li><a href="?p=services">services</a></li>
<li><a href="?p=about">about</a></li>
<li><a href="?p=blog">blog</a></li>
<li><a href="?p=portfolio" class="active">portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="?p=contact">contact</a></li>
<li><a href="?p=shop">shop</a></li>
</ul></nav>

    <a class="logreg" href="pages/logreg.php">Login / Register</a>
</header>
```

Comment: The active state image's width is bigger then the horizontal padding on the a tags. Try adjusting the width of the active image or adjusting the width of the padding.

Answer (score 1):

Yes pankijs correct you have to add padding left, for that just add padding left to **a** tag.

Check my screenshot

[image]
[image]

And it doesn't moves when you click.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wL4n36ed/3/)

```
nav a:link {
    color: #000000;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

thats it remove padding left property from a.active

```
nav a.active {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url("../icons/o.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
}
```

Comment: When I do what you say it moved the image over by the padding and creates an empty space between the link its attached to and the img

Comment: I think we need to add a width or padding to the li tag with the padding-left=30 on the nav a tag –

Comment: ok please check this link i have recreate the navigation for you https://jsfiddle.net/wL4n36ed/3/

Comment: Did you check this in the browser? Or did you just check it in the js fiddle?

Comment: What you showed me did not work for me in chrome. What did you change? Also, I removed all the padding all the margin and all the width. When I click the links at that point they stil lmove. I even removed the background image and the links still either shift left or right depending on which link I click.

Comment: It was the flot on nav and the float on li

Answer (score 0):

use the same padding you use for a.active (padding-left:30px;) globally for all a elements. don't change it on hover/active state and you will be good.

Comment: man this is not working for me, i tried nav a {
    color: #ffffff;
     padding-right:25px;
} no luck I eve added more padding and padding to both sides.

Comment: but you are using different left paddings, ofcourse changing right padding won't help

Comment: lol, Ya obviously if we know what wont help we would not be trying to figure out what will. And yes there is a problem with padding. Because when I move to home the images shift still and the images is to the left of home.

Comment: And if you add padding-left to all the a tags will this not take even more space up to the left of the a tag with the image to the left? All thats going to do is push things further left.

Comment: jesus, you have different left padding for different a element states, that is reason why stuff moves around... remove different padding for different states

Comment: but why then you want it to sit on the link on click (:active state)?

Comment: I want the background img to appear when the link is active and not be to close to the link to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a transparent image of the same size as `o.png` and supply it to `nav a` style similar to the way `nav a:active`.

Comment: I don't see why he downvoted you I think your answer is clever and got me closer then I am...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is floating left on the `li` and floating right on the `nav`
This is causing the links to shift left and then right depending on how the browser was translating the contradicting floats.

removing the `float` from `nav` resolved the issue.